# Bone Rotation in Pose Position

Tags: animation, rigging, motion-capture

I am trying to create Motion-Capture rig using blender, copying the rig from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UPZtS5LVvw

Everything is set up and supposed to be working fine, the only problem is that almost all of the bones rotate as soon as I switch the rig from rest mode to pose mode, causing the models torso to twist, the feet to be upside down and overall preventing me from using it for animation. Does anyone know why the bones rotate like this and how I can prevent it from happening?

Heres the link to the file:

[image]

Thanks in advance and goodbye

Answer (score 1):

I guess the wrong bone constraints were added. You can invert the constraint axis with the "invert" checkbox (as shown in linked Pic.). By inverting your two hip Bones (Hip_L, Hip_R) on the y axis I was able to untwist your model. You may have to invert other axis on other bones. Eventually, by playing around with those inverting options, you should be able to get the right orientation.

I hope that answers your question.

regards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently using a computer that can run Blender (school), and I've only spent only a few weeks in Blender so far, but here's my two cents:

One thing that might be wrong is that the keyframes don't have rotation.  Make sure that you're doing LocRotScale instead of LocScale.  If you go to the bottom-right area of the timeline editor, you should be able to set the box to default to LocRotScale when you press I if you want.